# What does __devexit mean in a function declaration?

Tags: c, function

A driver I looked at has

```
static void __devexit rtsx_remove(struct pci_dev *pci)
```

What does `__devexit` mean in the context of the function definition? Other functions I've seen have, at most, `static` and a return type.

Comment: This is attempt two at this question.  It seems the first attempt was so clouded with extraneous details that it was unanswered.  I wanted to delete the question, but stack-overflow warned that it was frowned upon, and I felt that an edit would make the previous answers look retrospectively irrelevant.  If anyone recommends choosing an edit/deletion instead, let me know.

Comment: Why don't you right click that `__devexit` symbol, go to its definition and see for yourself exactly what it means??? It is most likely just an annotation used in order to generate predefined warnings by an external tool which checks for coding correctness or something like that.

Comment: This is some macro in the Unix kernel: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/init.h

Comment: Note that you could have a function such as `static inline int max(int x, int y) { return (x > y) ? x : y; }` which adds an `inline` in there.  You could have an inline function that returns a constant pointer to (constant) volatile data, and all sorts of other stuff. And you could have a `static void _Noreturn inline exit_noisily(void) { fprintf(stderr, "Exiting\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`, etc. Microsoft used and/or uses various qualifiers, such as `far`, `near`, `cdecl`, `dllimport`, `dllexport`, etc (possibly with underscores attached). Your `__devexit` is another such qualifier.

Comment: @barakmanos I'm not using an IDE

Comment: @barakmanos Regardless, the definition (` __section(.devexit.text) __exitused __cold`) doesn't explain function structure.  Anyway, thanks for the answer.  If you post the answer as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why isn't ` __section(.devexit.text) __exitused __cold` hilighted as code?

Comment: That is no code, but finally results in some gcc-specific attributes. Check the gcc documentation about these. Note that none is a "prefix", but the first two are _specifiers_. C does not have any prefixes for functions.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=54b956b903607

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Long-ish story short:**

This is a macro that expands to a set of gcc *attributes*. They are a way of providing the compiler with special information about various stuff in your code, like, in this case, a function.

Different compilers have different syntaxis for this purpose, it isn't standartized. For example, gcc uses attributes, but other compilers use different constructs.

**Long-ish story long-ish:**

So, I'm no Linux kernel expert, but judging by the source code, this macro is used for [*Hotplug*](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hotplug). I believe it signifies that the function should do something with a specific device exiting.

For example, the function you provided seems to be from the set of Hotplug functions for working with a Realtek PCI-Express card reader driver.

What does that macro actually do? Well, let's take a closer look at the macro's definition:

```
#define __devexit        __section(.devexit.text) __exitused __cold
```

The first part is `__section(.devexit.text)`:

```
# define __section(S) __attribute__ ((__section__(#S)))
```

As you can see, this creates an `__attribute__(__section__())` with the section name being `".devexit.text"`. This means that gcc will compile the assembly code of a function with this attribute into a named section in the compiled binary with the name `.devexit.text` (instead of the default section).

The second part is `__exitused` (defined to something only if the `MODULE` macro is defined):

```
#define __exitused  __used
```

And `__used` is, depending on the gcc version, defined either like this:

```
# define __used                 __attribute__((__used__))
```

or like this:

```
# define __used                 __attribute__((__unused__))
```

The former makes sure the function that has this attribute is compiled even if it is not referenced anywhere. The latter suppresses compiler warnings in the same case, although it doesn't affect the compilation in any way.

And, finally, `__cold`:

```
#define __cold                  __attribute__((__cold__))
```

This is an attribute that informs the compiler that the function with this attribute is not going to be called often, so that it can optimize accordingly.

Sooo, what do we have in the end? Looks like functions marked with `__devexit` are **just functions that aren't called often** (if called at all), and stuffed into a named section.

All the source code was taken from [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=2.6.33#L81). It looks like the macro has now actually been [removed from the Linux Kernel](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=54b956b903607).

Answer (score 1):

"...It is most likely just an annotation..."  --barak manos

Eureka!  It turns out that the mystery element is maybe called an [annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx), which adds extra information about a function.  This extra information can be checked by the compiler to catch bugs that might otherwise go unnoticed.

Edit: @MattMcNabb says it's not an annotation.  Added uncertainty.

Comment: That could be quite a lot of things, as it is most likely a macro.

Comment: If it's [the Linux kernel __devexit](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.33;i=__devexit) then it's certainly not an "annotation".

Comment: @Kenkron: see the link in [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948952/what-does-devexit-mean-in-a-function-declaration#comment49937773_30948952) - it leads to a commit where the purpose of this macro and its brethren is briefly documented.

Answer (score 1):

These attributes were used in the Linux Kernel on certain driver functions and data declarations, putting them in a separate section that could be discarded under certain circumstances.

However, they are no longer used (or defined) from 3.10.x onward. See: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=54b956b903607